# Career Advice: Where to apply Analysis in Industry?

Tags: soft-question, advice

$\textbf{Background:}$ I am a fourth-year undergraduate at a major university in the US, and I will be staying for a fifth year before proceeding to pursue a masters degree. I have taken courses in analysis, up to and including Measure Theory, basic Complex Analysis, and first courses in Point-Set Topology and Algebra, as well as some introductory PDEs. Next year, I will be taking courses in Numerical Analysis as well as a course covering Abstract Measure Theory and basic Functional Analysis. I have however, no programming experience, though I will attain some over summer for Numerical Analysis, and I have no experience in other applied areas like engineering and so forth. Also, Analysis is my favorite area of math.

$\textbf{Concerns:}$ I have begun to notice that I do not want to go to math academia, as I have taken an interest in areas that apply analysis specifically.  Therefore I am considering switching for my masters, and go ahead and pursue a career where I could possibly use some Analysis, or an area which applies it\implements its results. However my knowledge of such professions is the equivalent of a null set in Measure Theory.

$\textbf{The Question:}$ I have noticed many users who did math as undergrads and now work in other areas. So I would like to ask what would be an area, say in engineering for instance, in which to get a masters and use some Analysis along the way, and which training, say programming for example, should I attain besides more pure math?

Note: If the question is too vague or should not be asked here, please mention it and I will edit or delete right away. Also, if the title is misleading, feel free to tell me or if you want to, correct it as well.

Thank you for your time and any advice provided.

Comment: Anything related to modelling fluid dynamics would fall into applications of PDE. It includes aerodynamics, but also climate/weather modelling. But numerical calculations are a must.